# Очищается List<Model2>

Tags: android, list, model, arraylist

Имеется класс Model1, который в себе содержит некоторые параметры и List.

```
    List<Model1>
Class Model1:
    private String param1;
    private String param2;
    private List<Model2> param3List= new ArrayList<>();
```

Загружаю данные сервера, делаю сет их во фрагмент

```
public void setServices(List<Model1> model1) {
        this.modelList1.clear();
        this.modelList1.addAll(model1);
    }
```

Далее, я эти данные проверяю и в адаптер добавляю param3List

```
list.clear();
for (Model2 m2 : modelList1) {
        list.addAll(m2.getParam3List());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
}
```

И вот по непонятной причине, один раз list.clear() очищает только лист, который в адаптере, а в другой раз очищает и лист который в адаптере и вместе с ним param3List, который находится в modelList1.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Приведите более подробно порядок действий. В данный момент из разрозненных кусков кода в чём проблема составить представление сложно.

Comment: Есть некий список оплат, есть возможность повторной оплаты и возможность создания оплаты, если после загрузки этого списка попробовать сделать повторную оплату, какой-нибудь уже присутствующей в списке, то всё в норме, все параметры оплаты загружаются и ничего не очищается, а если создать оплату, а потом её же еще раз попробовать повторно оплатить, то в список параметров оплаты подгружаются все данные, кроме данных списка описанных выше, вот как раз в этот момент он и очищается, почему-то

Comment: Мало подробностей, а ваши уточнения врядли к делу относятся. У вас либо в архитектуре проблема, либо вы где-то новый объект списка ссылке назначаете вместо пользования старым. Мало кода - одни догадки.

Comment: Полагаю что ссылки указывают на один и тот же `List` например. Учитывая что в `set` методе вы не делаете нормальный `set`, а фактически добавляете элемента в один и тот же список, очищая его... Есть вообще причины, по которым это именно так реализовано?

Comment: Больше кода не даст какого-либо толку. Я скинул основные зависимости, что за чем идёт и что кого вызывает.

Comment: @iksuy Интересует именно почему set так реализован? Я делаю сет этого списка всего один раз, при загрузке данных, до этого я их через get брал с места где они грузились, но они там тоже очищались, решил не брать оттуда, а сетить сюда, тоже самое получается, очищается элемент списка, почему-то.

Comment: Зачем чистить существующий список, если можно просто присвоить новый? Почему не написать в сеттере `this.modelList1 = model1`?

Comment: а списки разве так присваиваются?

Comment: Эээ, ну да, конечно...

Answer (score 1):

Список - это объект в памяти. На него может ссылаться одна или несколько переменных-ссылок.

Когда вы хотите с одним списком работать из разных переменных вы один раз его присваиваете разным ссылкам. В этом случае, через любую переменную вы можете очистить этот список.

Если вам надо иметь разные, независимые списки в разных переменных, то вам надо создать разные объекты.

```
List<Model2> someList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Model2> sameList  = someList; //тот же объект. изменения в нём отразятся на someList 

List<Model2> anotherList  = new ArrayList<>(sameList); //новый объект.
//изменения этого объекта не отразятся на someList и sameList
```

Comment: Ну вот я так и сделал, а изменения на нём всё равно отражаются

Comment: @5mi13, попробуйте обновлённый код. И убедитесь, что вы нигде потом не переназначаете ссылку на список.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую этот вариант. Если не получится - отпишусь.